# WPF: Non focusable window

Tags: wpf, focus

I am developing WPF Touch Screen Keyboard.

I need to know how is it possible to make main window non focusable, so other windows will be receiving the input when I click on virtual keyboard buttons.

Simple applying "Focusable="False"" to the main window and all child controls doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a clickable attribute you can set to false which stops the form receiving click messages.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by using Popup instead of Window, which not grab the focus, when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41ca3605-247c-4c5b-ac5d-74ce5abd7b92/making-a-window-invisible-to-mouse-events-ishittestvisiblefalse-not-working?forum=wpf

I've figured out how to do this.  The key being the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag for the window's extended style.You can set the topmost property like you normally would, then this code takes care of making the window transparent to mouse clicks:

Code Snippet

```
public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

// Get this window's handle
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

// Change the extended window style to include WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Comment: It seems you want to set `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;` instead (had no luck with WS_EX_TRANSPARENT) if you want a non-focusable window, works on windows 10 at least.